# CDC-Debezium capture data in chain

Tags: debezium

CDC-Debezium captures event e.g. Insert, Update or Delete once such event occurs in source system e.g. postgres and it streams data and sends to destination system e.g. NoSQL or Apache-Kafka. I'm very new in this configuration and setup.

I would like to know if there's any way to capture chains of tables while any event triggers e.g. Suppose there's Table A Parent and B Child in source system. Now there's some change occurs in table B it's been successfully captured and flows to destination system. Now I would require some method or configuration in CDC-Debezium which will be able to capture that change has been made in table B and this table is dependent of Table A though no changes occurs on Table A or Vice-Versa.

Please let me know thoughts in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

please check these links, they might be a good starter for the discussion
https://debezium.io/blog/2018/09/20/materializing-aggregate-views-with-hibernate-and-debezium/
https://debezium.io/blog/2018/03/08/creating-ddd-aggregates-with-debezium-and-kafka-streams/
https://debezium.io/blog/2018/03/08/creating-ddd-aggregates-with-debezium-and-kafka-streams/

Comment: Thanks. I'll check and get back if any doubt there.